# derivative of a map $f(A)=AA^*$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Can someone help me with the derivative of this function. I am getting confused

$f:GL(n,\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow GL(n,\mathbb{C})$

$A \rightarrow AA^{*}$ where $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose of A.

So I get $df_{A}(B) = lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{f(A+hB)-f(A)}{h} = ... = lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{I_n + \bar{h}AB^*+hBA^*+h\bar{h}I_n}{h} $

I am not sure how to go from here. h is in $\mathbb{C}$, right? Am I making some kind of mistake. Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks :)

Edit: This is part of a problem I am solving in differential topology. So in the problem A is in the unitary group, that is  $AA^* = I$. So I'll have $f^{-1}(I) = U(n)$

Comment: How did you get the identity matrix there?

Comment: Oops sorry forgot to mention. I'll edit right now

Comment: You forgot to subtract the identity matrix!

Answer (score 1):

You should have

$$f(A+hB) $$
$$=(A+hB)(A+hB)^*$$
$$=(A+hB)(A^*+\overline{h}B^*)$$

$$=AA^* +hBA^* + \overline{h}AB^* + |h|^2 BB^*$$

so $f(A+hB)-f(A) = hBA^* + \overline{h}AB^* + |h|^2 BB^*$. Divide by $h$ and take the limit!

Comment: Where did the Identity go that we get from $AA^*$?

Comment: aaah, just read your comment! Thank you so much :)